# Nested join with Eloquent

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

In MySQL I can do a nested join. With Eloquent is it possible?

```
LEFT JOIN users_permissions (
    INNER JOIN permissions
        ON permissions.id = user_permissions.id_permission

    LEFT JOIN permissions_feature
        ON permissions_feature.id = user_permissions.id_permission_feature
) ON users_permissions.user_id = users.id
```

Basically, the first `LEFT JOIN` will works if `ON` matches, but it requires that `INNER JOIN` match too. Additionally, another `LEFT JOIN` is done if all works.

With Eloquent it seems not be possible, because `JoinClause` don't have a `join()` method.

Comment: I'm also looking answer for the similar problem. Any luck?

Comment: @NBhargav nothing until now. :(